# Running unverified publisher batch files with powershell

Tags: security, powershell, batch-file

In my powershell script I call a handful of batch files. For each batch file I get the "publisher could not be verified warning" and I have to click run for it to work. This poses some problems for automating this script

Without changing settings on the machine itself, can I make this issue go away?

Comment: What level is your `Get-ExecutionPolicy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you right clic on these script files in explorer do you see in the general tab :

Security : this file come from ...

[image]

you can remove it using :

```
echo "">file.ps1:Zone.Identifier
```

You'll find more explanation [here](http://www.silogix.fr/Blog-Silogix/gerer-les-alternate-data-streams-avec-cmd-powershell-2-et-powershell-3.aspx) :